# Add a callback to an existing colorbox call?

Tags: jquery, callback, colorbox

I have an existing call to open an iframe colorbox when a link of class "iframe" is clicked:

`$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"200px", height:"500px"});`

I'd like to add a callback to this colorbox to trigger a function when it's about to open:

`onOpen:function(){ alert('colorbox is about to open'); }`

but where does this code go? I tried adding it to the colorbox() but then the whole thing fails. I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it goes as an option as below:

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"200px", height:"500px",onOpen:function(){ alert('colorbox is about to open'); }});
```

Or

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"200px", height:"500px",onOpen:openCallBack});

function openCallBack(){
//do something here
}
```

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4CNN8/) is a working example.